# Как статической переменной задать значение глобальной $_SERVER внутри класса?

Tags: php, ооп

Статическому свойству $url_a необходимо получить информацию из глобальной переменной $_SERVER

```
    public static $url_a = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];//так не работает
```

Можно лишь задать ей это значение через метод, но я хочу использовать эту переменную/свойство для нескольких статичных методов, и в каждом создавать это свойство по новой - глупо.
Вот пример кода как я пытался:

```
class SwitchPage {
public static $url_a;
public function __construct() {
    $this -> for_construct();
}
public static function for_construct(){
    self::$url_a = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
public static function url() {
    return self::$url_a;
}
}
echo SwitchPage::url();
```

Ожидается что метод url() вернёт адрес страницы, но он не возвращает ничего

Comment: Вопрос - а почему всё это должно быть статикой? если все нестатичным сделать? ..................." но я хочу использовать эту переменную/свойство для нескольких статичных методов" --- тогда сделать метод геттер. в котором будет возвращаться $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: `public static function url() { return 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; }`